# How to write test case for duplicating a Row except its ID in Jhipster test case?

Tags: jhipster, testcase

I want to write a test for a method of `duplicatingRow()` in Jhipster.
Customer1 is already in table If I need to duplicate it all attributes should have same value except `id`. id is autogenerated here.

My method is

```
@PostMapping("/duplicatingRow")
@Timed

public ResponseEntity<Customer> duplicatingRow(@RequestBody Customer customer) throws URISyntaxException {
    Optional<Customer> duplicatecustomer = customerRepository.findById(customer.getId());
    Customer custom = duplicatecustomer.get();
    custom.setId(null);

    Customer result = customerRepository.save(custom);

    return ResponseEntity.ok().build();
```

my test case is

```
@Test
@Transactional
public void duplicateCustomer() throws Exception {

    // Initialize the database
    customerRepository.saveAndFlush(customer);      
    int databaseSizeBeforeUpdate = customerRepository.findAll().size();

    restCustomerMockMvc.perform(post("/api/duplicatecustomers")
                .contentType(TestUtil.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8)
                .content(TestUtil.convertObjectToJsonBytes(customer)))
                .andExpect(status().isOk()).andDo(print());

      // Validate the Customer in the database 
    List<Customer> customerList = customerRepository.findAll();
    assertThat(customerList).hasSize(databaseSizeBeforeUpdate +1); 
    Customer testCustomer1 = customerList.get(customerList.size() -1);
    System.out.print("test pro is"+testCustomer1);      

}
```

But if I run the test case I got error, it makes the original customer id to NULL. I don't know want to do. How can I create new Duplicate Row without affecting original one???

Comment: This is normal because you're not duplicating an entity, you're modifying an existing one because Hibernate tracks it. See https://vladmihalcea.com/clone-duplicate-entity-jpa-hibernate/

Comment: Actually I created duplication of an existing row with new id. But it doesn't works with test case. My problem is with test case

Comment: In database both rows are present the original and duplicated row id only differs